# Closing msgbox from another file

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using several excel files and each one is making some calculations using VBA. Now I'm working on one file which will run each file one after another and calculate them all with one click. Unfortunately at the end of calculation for each file there is Msgbox "Report updated" and my macro stops and is waiting to confirm "OK" manually before it will close first file and open next one.
I cannot remove this lines with msgboxes because some people will use just one file and they need to be informed that everything is finished.
And here is my question: How can I close this msgbox automatically?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't unless you modify the code. If several users open the files and some of them need the msgbox, I'm afraid the only solution is to modify the code and combine it `Environ("Username")` so the code detect if YOU open the files, then no msgbox, but it's not you, then show msgbox. I would suggest you to change all msgbox in all files, and replace them with `Application.Statusbar= "your info"`. There you can type how the process is going and when all is done, just type `Application.StatusBar=""` and you will reset it to default value (something like ready).

Comment: What about `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`?

Comment: Unfortunately it works only for system alerts e.g. question if save a file when you are closing it ot for msgbox.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is impossible, because MsgBox is modal. But why your macro displays it at first? You may add conditional instruction that checks if the sheet on which it works is displayed. Something like:

```
If ActiveSheet.Name = wsProcessedSheet.Name Then MsgBox "Report updated"
```

So, the message will be displayed for normal user and not for your supermacro. Alternatively, you could disable the MsgBox only for your machine:

```
If Environ("username")<> "your user name" Then MsgBox "Report updated"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for interesting ideas.
I've just figured out different solution. Originally I had button which run macro Update()

```
Sub Update()
  ...calculations....
  Msgbox "Report updated"
End Sub
```

Now I removed msgbox from this macro and created two macroslike below:

```
Sub ButtonClick()
  Call Update
  Msgbox "Report updated"
End Sub

Sub Update()
  ...calculations....
End Sub
```

And now button is running macro ButtonClick and in external file I can use macro Update() which didn't contain msgbox.

But I still wondering if there is any way to confirm msgbox alerts